# How to check List for value in a specific range of values in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

Say I have a list with random values

```
11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88
```

I want to extract all values between `20-60` lets say which uses the value lets say `40` with offsets `-20` and `+20`.

so I should get `22,33,44,55` only

Code

```
uint Val = 40;
List<uint> List1 = new List<uint>() {11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88};
List<uint> CheckedList = List1.Where(t => (Val - 20) >= t && t <= (Val + 20));
```

I tried this code and I cannot get it to compile Linq is very difficult to grasp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Append `ToList` if you want a list:

```
List<uint> CheckedList = List1.Where(t => t >= (Val - 20) && t <= (Val + 20)).ToList();
```

Comment: insane, just like that the problem is solved, I surely thought the linq equation was off. Ya it was too good to be true still doesn't work in the proper range, turns too much values.

Comment: @SSpoke - Nothing wrong with parentheses , your condition itself is wrong. It should be `List<uint> CheckedList = List1.Where(t => t >= (Val - 20) && t <= (Val + 20)).ToList();` Check Update.

Comment: @RahulSingh thank you now its more cleaner and understandable works perfect. A+

Answer (score 1):

You can Try this

```
List<uint> rangeList=new List<uint>();
foreach(var values in List1)
{
  if(values>=(val-20) && values<=(val+20))
  {
       rangeList.Add(values);
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah I was looking for a quick linq 1 liner but if it's not possible I will use this one, it's not that long too

Answer (score 1):

LINQ methods mostly return `IEnumerable<T>`, to get a `List` you can either use `ToList` method:

```
 List<uint> CheckedList = List1.Where(t => (Val - 20) >= t && t <= (Val + 20))
                               .ToList();
```

or call a [List constructor that takes `IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx) :

```
 List<uint> CheckedList = new List<uint>(list1.Where(t => (Val - 20) >= t && t <= (Val + 20)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<uint> CheckedList = List1.Where(t => t>= (Val - 20)  && t <= (Val + 20)).ToList();
```

Result: 22,33,44 and 55.